# How can I pass around domNodes with bindings to other controllers/directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to Angular, but learning quickly. However, the one problem that I haven't been able to find an answer for yet is how I can pass around HTML snippets with bindings attached.

e.g. With jQuery I could do something like

```
var $div = $('<div id="test"><button>CLICK ME!</button></div>');
$div.delegate('button', 'click', function () { alert('CLICKED') });
```

Then I could pass around this `$div` variable to other objects. For instance I would use this pattern to separate page specific content from the code of a modal Singleton that encapsulated general functionality.

e.g.

```
var name = "The Dude";
var $div = $('<div id="test"><button>CLICK ME!</button></div>');
$div.delegate('button', 'click', function () { alert('Hi, ' + name) });
Modal.open({ content: $div});
```

How can I achieve something similar with Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass around template code in the controllers, that's not the "angular way". If you have to do DOM manipulation it should stay in a directive. A lot of jQuery developers fall into this trap of thinking like you do with jQuery. But anyways here's how I would solve this problem:

I'm writing this in a directive so it's more modular. You could move this into a controller and it'll work just fine.

Code in plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/epUT9upFxRETKqZ5BUAh?p=preview)

In the directive you have a template which contains your code and you can have a `ng-click` binding which can control a click action to open the modal.

Now as far as the content in the modal is concerned, making the actual template code modular so you can decouple the content from the template depends on if/what angular plugins you're using. They all do something similar but the names may be a little different. For example, if you're using [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)(which is awesome by the way, if you dont use any plugins I'd highly recommend it) there's a **resolve** function that takes a variable as an argument and you can display that in the view. That's exactly what you want to send custom content to the modal(eg. name)